# If I took electives from another program during my BSc and MSc, how should I list it on my CV?

Tags: masters, mathematics, computer-science, cv, bachelor

While I was doing my BSc in Applied Mathematics I took 5 electives that were part of the Data Science MSc program. Right now I am pursing a MSc in Computer Science at the same school and I'm taking two courses that are also part of the Data Science MSc. When I finish my master's program in a year, I will have also taken another two courses that are part of the Data Science program.

So, in total I will have taken 9 courses part of the Data Science program. Since the Data Science program has 11 courses in total, I was thinking on saying that during my BSc and MSc I took 9 out of 11 courses part of the Data Science master's program and list it something like the following (it wasn't actually at Harvard, it's just an example):

- 2014: Applied Mathemaics BSc
  Harvard College, Cambridge, MA.
- 2017: Computer Science MSc
  Harvard College, Cambridge, MA.
- Additional coursework: Data Science MSc
  Harvard College, Cambridge, MA.
  Took 9 out of 11 courses from the program (not officially enrolled).

Do you think it's okay to do it this way?

Comment: I think it comes across as braggy to put this in the same list as your actual degrees. Especially since the data science classes most likely also counted toward your CS degree, so are not truly "additional." I've seen "Graduate Coursework" sections on the CVs of newish grad students; that might be a safer bet.

Answer (score 2):

You shouldn't. This is what your transcripts are for.
If you truly need to point out your data science experience, note briefly when you refer to your education, in the cover/application letter, that this information can be found there.
If you don't think your transcript reflects well enough to refer to, then mentioning the courses without a willingness to back that claim up, will come across as suspicious.

Comment: "You shouldn't" is not an answer to "how". An answer would be "you do it as follows ..." or "ill-posed/unclear question" or "it can't be done". If the OP runs into problems while listing the courses in his/her CV, it's his/her problem.

Comment: @LeonMeier "You shouldn't" is definitely an answer to "How should I...?".  Moreover, in this instance, I believe it's the _correct_ answer.  OP is asking for advice; writing off the premise of their question as "his/her problem" is not providing good advice.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is a good idea to have them listed in the CV. But be brief as brief as possible and make sure you have acquired enough knowledge to face the questions on them during tough situations in interviews/presentations.